# NSDictionary Inside An NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *golferIconsu = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferIconsFirstScene"];

NSMutableDictionary *golferIconsSceneOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:golferIconsu];

NSMutableDictionary *savedScoreCards;

NSMutableDictionary *currentScoreCard;
[currentScoreCard setObject:golferIconsSceneOne forKey:@"golferIconsFirstScene"];

NSMutableDictionary *GI = [currentScoreCard objectForKey:@"golferIconsFirstScene"];

[savedScoreCards setObject:currentScoreCard forKey:@"1"];

NSLog([golferIconsSceneOne objectForKey:@"30101"]);
NSLog([GI objectForKey:@"30101"]);
```

At the end all that is printed out in my log is the first `NSLog` call, not the second one. For example:

```
NSLog([golferIconsSceneOne objectForKey:@"30101"]);
```

This prints out a string that I stored in that dictionary.

This one:

```
NSLog([GI objectForKey:@"30101"]);
```

Doesn't print out anything at all.

How can I get the `NSDictionary` GI to have the exact same properties as `golferIconsSceneOne`, but I need to do this using the `currentScoreCardDictionary`, which contains `golferIconsSceneOne`?

Comment: you haven't allocated memory to savedScoreCards and currentScoreCard ?? how it is working

Comment: whatever you are using you have to allocated it.

Comment: Can you post the answer showing me how to alloc the variables I need to allocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise your dictionary before setting object in it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *savedScoreCards = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *currentScoreCard = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yep, currentScoreCard is `nil`, so GI will be `nil` and `[GI objectForKey..` will not print anything when you do the NSLog

Comment: Hot Licks Only class members are initialized to `nil` so according to me it should crash.. but I don't know how it was working

Answer (score 1):

Do like this intialize one and set it into other

```
NSMutableDictionary *savedScoreCards = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *currentScoreCard = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:savedScoreCards];
```